# Opening Rdata file on R

Tags: r, file, rdata, setwd

I have some trouble to open Rdata files on Rstudio.

I tried different directory.

I tried the `load()` function.

I set up the file pathway with `setwd()`.

I made sure that the file pathway did not contain spaces or accent or particular character in it.

I tried the function `load(file.choose())`.

The file is 8.4 Mb (so not empty).

But it keeps saying:

> "Object is not found"

It is downloaded from the internet but when I try `load(url())` it says:

> "cannot open the connection", however I do have internet connection.
>   It also says "status was 'Couldn't connect to server' ".

Any thoughts ?
Any ideas to solve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the full path to locate the file.

1. Locate the file on your computer. Let's assume the location is `C:/Downloads/thedata.RData`
2. Check if R sees that this file exists `file.exists("C:/Downloads/thedata.RData")`
3. If this returns TRUE then the file is there. Try loading `load("C:/Downloads/thedata.RData")`
4. Otherwise if `file.exists()` is FALSE then the file was not reachable. Try moving it to another place and try again

---

The error you get is `Object not found`. This error message doesn't seem to be used within the `load()` function. It can occur if the file-path is missing the surrounding quotes.

Maybe you forgot to quote the filename?

```
> load(myfile.RData)
```

> Error in load(myfile.RData) : object 'myfile.RData' not found

```
> load("myfile.RData")
# Works without error.
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I tried your function. Actually is says TRUE, so the file is detected but when I afterwards run the load function, it keeps saying "object is not found". I tried anyhow another place and it is not working.

Comment: You said that the file is downloaded from the internet. Can you provide an URL, or is it private?

Comment: Also expanded the answer about your error - maybe you forgot to quote the filename? (put it inside " ")

Comment: Yes the URL is private, sorry. I actually did not forget to use the quotes.

Comment: In that case can you show us the full error message you get?

Comment: > Error in load(url("------/mod_europe_un_beta_g9.Rdata")) : 
  cannot open the connection to '------/mod_europe_un_beta_g9.Rdata'
De plus : Warning message:
  In load(url("------/mod_europe_un_beta_g9.Rdata")) :
  URL '------/mod_europe_un_beta_g9.Rdata': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'

Comment: This is the error you should be getting when using `url`. What about the error when trying to load the downloaded file?

Comment: Oh sorry. there's no error when I run the load function. But when I run the object, it says "Object 'mod_europe_un_beta_g9' is not found"

Comment: After loading the data do `ls()` to see what objects are available. Maybe you are trying to use an object that was not in the file.

Comment: Okay I understood the problem. The object I tried to open was supposed to be the result of a model (a highly consuming model that a guy ran for me). But the guy kept the name of the model and actually gave several file (database, vector, result of the model, function...) so I was trying to read an environment. Thank you for ls() function Karolis, you helped me a lot !